# Infer type information inside if-constexpr

Tags: auto, decltype, if-constexpr

I want to explore the feature of **if-constexpr** and try to figure out type information at compile-time.
For this purpose, I write the following code.
I expect that **printTypeInfo** function will return 4 for x and 3.24 for y. However, it gives me 3.1 and 3.24.
I don't know where goes wrong.
[image]

I wish decltype will infer the type to int, but it seems infer to double.
When I replace **decltype** with following code, it works.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6ipn.png)

Comment: It seems decltype infer x to double.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`decltype(value)` in your example will always be `const T&`, since that's your parameter type. References aren't integral, so you always add `0.1`. You could use `std::remove_reference_t` to get the underlying type:

```cpp
auto printTypeInfo(const auto& value) {
    if constexpr (std::is_integral_v<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(value)>>) {
        return v + 1;
    } else {
        return v + 0.1;
    }
}
```